# I created a new folder on the terminal and is not shown in the finder

Tags: terminal, finder, mojave

I came across this issue in my new mac book pro. I created a folder using iterm and I have some content on it (I cloned a git repo). When I go to finder I don't see it.

So maybe I'm not in the right folder... but I tried to create the folder in the finder and I get the "folder already exists" error but still I don't see it.

Im using mojave 10.14.1

Comment: show us how you did it in iterm

Answer (score 4):

One of the most probable cause for this to happen is that you inadvertently entered a name which the `Finder` isn't able to display correctly (or doesn't display to protect us from the complexity of the underlying Unix filesystem).

To check this hypothesis, please from `iTerm` go into the parent directory of the one you created let's say its name is `foo bar` and enter:

```
ls -aBdl 'foo bar'
```

The `-B` option will display any non printable character as a `\xxx` where `xxx` is the octal value of the non printable character.
This option is very helpful to deal with filenames which cause problems to shells and graphical interfaces like the `Finder`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you gave it a very common name you can use `locate filename` from the terminal. This will list all occurrences of the character string 'filename'. It lists the complete path of all the matches it finds. I would go to the directory above the one you thought you created file in and run the locate command from there.

Comment: The database used by `locate` usually lags behind the actual content of the disk. Might be better to run `find ~ -type d -name FOLDERNAME` instead.

Comment: Yep. i knew that but forgot. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: You can immediately update the database by on a Mac by typing sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb but this may take longer than you wish to wait.